# How to create link to a view

Tags: 8, navigation

I've a view with a page display on url `"progetti"`.

On my controller I'm trying to create a link to this url but I can't find the right way. I've added `\Drupal\Core\Url` namespace on top of the file.

I'm creating an items list:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('progetti');
$variables['items'][]['value'] = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => array('#value' => 'sergio'),
  '#url' => $url,
);
```

It doesn't work, also if I use `"/progetti"` as argument.

Logs say:

```
PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "progetti" does not exist."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to create url object from a path instead of route, use the function [fromUri()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x) instead of `fromRoute()`.

```
$url  = Url::fromUri('internal:/progetti');
$variables['items'][]['value'] = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => array('#value' => 'sergio'),
  '#url' => $url,
);
```

In fromUri() function you need to pass the URI of the resource including the scheme. For user input that may correspond to a Drupal route, use internal: for the scheme.

Comment: It would be best to explain why the use of `internal:/` or `fromUri` instead of just providing a working code answer.